# Chat messages ordering strategy in PubNub

Tags: android, time, pubnub

We are building a chat application in Android and having a hard time deciding the message ordering strategy for the messages. Uptil now, we have been using device time for the sent messages and server time for the received messages. We realised this strategy can fail very easily if the device time is out of sync with server time.

As an alternative, we are planning to use the device time for both sent and received messages to maintain correct ordering. To account for cases, where device time can be incorrectly set, we plan to show a toast to the user if the PubNub timetoken received in the Publish callback is way off from the user's device time. Code snippet below:

Is this an acceptable strategy for the message ordering? Are there better alternatives.

```
public void successCallback(String channel,
                                        Object message) {
                if (channel.equals(getUserChannel())) {

                    JSONArray messageDetails = (JSONArray) message;

                    if(messageDetails.length() >2)
                        try {
                            long timeToken = Long.parseLong(messageDetails.getString(2));

                            timeToken = timeToken / 10000;

                            changeMessageStatus(chatMessage.getMobileId(), Status.SENT);

                            long diffValue = timeToken - Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

                            if(Math.abs(diffValue) > Constants.TIME_DIFF_THRESHOLD)
                            {
                                applicationHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.incorrect_time), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });

                            }

                            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Diff Time: " + String.valueOf(diffValue));

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

                pubnub.unsubscribeAll();
            }
```

Comment: Madhur - let me know if this KB is helpful.
http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/195/how-do-i-synchronize-multiple-devices#latest

Comment: Wait that's about time sync vs Chat Message Ordering.  You can use PubNub time Sync API to get a general time sync method for the devices and use that as the timeline for each device independent of Time Zone.  That will work pretty well actually!

Comment: Excellent idea Craig!

Comment: @MadhurAhuja I have problem when order message. I have published message from python and subcribe on browser. The order of messages on browser is not correct. It seem you have resolve this issue. Could you tell me how to order the chat messages?

Comment: @ToujouAya See the response below by Stephen. You will have to order it manually by timestamping each message and aggregating at the receiver end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## How do I order Chat Messages on multiple devices in multiple timezones?

PubNub provides a `time` API which can be used to synchronize clients (each having its own latency) within a millisecond of each other. This can be done by creating a minimum buffer amount of time (wait time) for which all devices agree to move forward after acknowledging the signal. You can use this Time Sync API to create an **Order ID** for each message.  First you need to store the client delta drift and calculate the current time.

Follow these basic steps to sync devices with independent latencies:

1. Determine the local time (in milliseconds): `start = now()`
2. Load the server timetoken: `timetoken = http://pubsub.pubnub.com/time/0`
3. Calculate the delay latency for a timetoken request:  `delay = now() - start`
4. Convert server timetoken into milliseconds: `timetoken = timetoken/10000`
5. Add a delay to compensate for latency: `message_order_id = timetoken + delay`

Use `message_order_id` to synchronize all devices to fire at a particular clock time.  The `message_order_id` is essentially your new **message OrderID** that can be used to render the message on screen.  When you publish a chat message, include the `message_order_id` as an entry in the dictionary.

```
message_order_id = timetoken + delay // new message order id
pubnub.publish({ message : { order_id : message_order_id, message : "Hi!" } });
```